# Porquê um campo texto é preenchido automaticamente pelo Chrome sem ser solicitado (e sendo hidden, ainda por cima?)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Uso a versão 68.0.3440.106 (Versão oficial) 64 bits, mas a reclamação abaixo vêm de diversos usuários. Não tenho como verificar as versões de todos.

Uso um mesmo sistema, criado por mim, desde o ano passado. Apenas neste ano aconteceu o problema abaixo - e apenas com o Chrome.

Desenho básico da índex:

Um mesmo form, hidden por padrão, com três fieldsets, cada qual com campos diferentes, mas direcionando para uma mesma página de conferência de dados, via ajax. Botão submit único.

Na índex, menu com três opções:

1. Candidato com CPF -> display o form -> display no fieldset com campo texto com nome e id “cpf”, máscara CPFbr (jQuery);
2. Candidato sem CPF (passaporte ou registro de estrangeiro) -> display o form -> display o fieldset com campo texto com nome e id “pass”, sem máscara;
3. Candidato já inscrito -> display o form -> display o fieldset com campos login (id e nome “login_sel") e password (id e nome “senha_sel”), para diferenciar de login e senha “normais” do site (em outra página, diga-se de passagem);

Como já disse, o botão submit é visualizado em todos os três comandos, em fieldset próprio.

O único problema é na opção “3”. Segue abaixo o exemplo do console quando alguém já inscrito preenche login e senha:

```
    cpf: 
    pass: Carlos
    login_sel: emaildosinscrito@qualquer
    senha_sel: jiu-z9V-fMb
    email_sel:
```

Como descrevi acima, na opção 3, os campos "cpf“ e “pass" estão hidden e vazios por padrão.
Funciona perfeitamente bem em todos os navegadores - incluindo IE e Edge (quem diria...), menos no Chrome, que insiste em colocar meu primeiro nome no campo “pass”. E isto não acontecia no ano passado...

Tentei primeiro uma redundância pelo Jquery: ao clicar na opção 3, esconde o que já está escondido (fieldsets para cpf e pass) e ainda limpa os campos hidden destes fieldsets... dá igual.

Só consegui solução fazendo uma gambiarra na página de conferência, mandando o código ignorar o campo “pass” quando login_sel e senha_sel estiverem preenchidos.

Desde já, thanks.

Comment: Já verificou se a opção de autopreenchimento de formulário está ligado no browser? Não sei guardaria os campos hidden, mas é um teste a se fazer.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nisso e veja se funciona: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30976223/1377664

Comment: Oi Badaro, tanto faz estar ou não ligado, a resposta é a mesma.

Dei também uma olhada, Sam, no link que vc. enviou e pelo que entendi uma das maneiras seria colocar o campo senha antes de qualquer campo e/ou criar campos “fake” - com diversas gambiarras.

Nada funcionou. O que me intriga é porque raios o Chrome inventou (ano passado não tinha esse problema) que tem que preencher com meu primeiro nome de login um campo de nome “pass", hidden e vazio por padrão, e dentro de um fieldset tb. hidden.

Ok, o nome do campo é “pass”, similar a “password”. Seria isso? I don’t believe!

Comment: Em cima do meu comentário acima sobre o problema ser o nome ter “pass”, de “password”: troquei o nome do campo para “ncpf” e.... mesma coisa.